# Is the "my going there" the same as "if I go there"?

Tags: grammar

I want to say;

> If I go there, there will be a problem.

Is it possible to say is as below;

> My going there will create a problem.

Feel free to provide different examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's be fine to say! You could also use:

- By going there, I'll create a problem.
- In going there, I'll create a problem.

Sorry that this answer couldn't be more substantial, but yours worked just fine!